# Android Swipe Gesture that parent Activity can not intercept

Tags: java, android, android-layout, swipe, gesture

I worked on android swipe gestures, i applied swipe gesture on Item inside recycler view and recycler view is inside fragment and then fragment is inside activity and activity has Scroll View, The problem was that parent activity was intercepting swipe gesture of item inside child recycler view, After so much hard i found solution and this code is working fine, Is there any other better solution to this problem? if yes then post it in answer otherwise vote my code so that i can use it in my app without any fear of failure. Here is my code

```
      listingView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(myContext)
        {


        public void onClick() {
            ViewListing();
        }
        //           @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


            switch (event.getActionMasked())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x1 = event.getX();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    LockableScrollView.setScrollingEnabled(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    x2 = event.getX();
                    float deltaX = x2 - x1;

                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > 20)
                    {
                        LockableScrollView.setScrollingEnabled(false);
                        // Left to Right swipe action
                        if (x2 > x1)
                        {
                            hideSidePanel();
                            LockableScrollView.setScrollingEnabled(true);

                        }

                        else
                        //MH: Right to Left Swipe
                        {

                            showSidePanel();
                            LockableScrollView.setScrollingEnabled(true);
                        }

                    }
                    break;

            }
            return super.onTouch(v, event);
        }


    });
```

Lockable Scroll View code

```
             public class LockableScrollView extends ScrollView {

   @Override
   public void setClipChildren(boolean clipChildren) {
    clipChildren=false;
    super.setClipChildren(clipChildren);
  }

  @Override
  public void setFocusable(int focusable) {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        focusable=View.NOT_FOCUSABLE;
      }
       super.setFocusable(focusable);
 }

 // true if we can scroll (not locked)
 // false if we cannot scroll (locked)
 private static boolean mScrollable = true;

 public LockableScrollView(Context context) {
     super(context);
 }

 public LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
 }

   public LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int     defStyleAttr)    {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  public LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int    defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
  }

 public static void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mScrollable = enabled;
  }

public static boolean isScrollable() {
    return  mScrollable;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //MH: if we can scroll pass the event to the superclass
            if (mScrollable) return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            //MH: only continue to handle the touch event if scrolling enabled
            return mScrollable; // mScrollable is always false at this point
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
  }

@Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    //MH: Don't do anything with intercepted touch events if
    //MH: we are not scrollable
    if (!mScrollable) return false;
    else return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

   }
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement swipe to dismiss for recyclerview items?

Comment: no i am implement slide to show and hide menu with animation and it is working fine, just need better idea or approval of this code

Comment: the menu is placed above recycler view item  as layout